Karate Robot desktop automation clicking button not working
I am trying to click on a button in a desktop application using the button label name,
I am getting the below error

this is the button i am trying to click

I have tessdata folder which has trained data as below

Can someone please guide me whats the issue here, i tried few ways, i am able to locate the window and window is getting highlighted but click fails

I guess you have followed the steps here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide - and I can't think of any other things to try. note that the tesseract support is experimental. do try to get others in your team to help out and contribute code to the open-source project if needed

Thank you Peter will try and get back to the comment if it works, will work with team to contribute to the code as you said. thanks

It did not work after the configuration but i tries with clicking using image using below code and it worked
Scenario:

robot { window: '^BATPC', highlight: true, highlightDuration: 5000 }
locate('Contact Center.png').click()

